# jQuery - how do you select the previous chosen Select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given this select element:

```
<select id="foo"> 
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

And I select the option 1 first, how do I retrieve the value of 1 after I choose 2 in this select dropdown using jQuery?

Comment: Just save it to a variable or an attribute on the select itself (my preference)? :) Please show the code you have attempted.

Comment: Store the value (or the option number or ID) in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the previous selection, stored it in a variable or as an attribute on the select itself (attributes are my preference as you can see them in the DOM inspector), example below:

```
$('#foo').change(function(){

    // Get previous value (if any)
    var lastValue = $(this).attr("data-lastvalue"); // or $(this).data("lastvalue"); 

    // Do stuff

    // Save new value
    $(this).attr("data-lastvalue", $(this).val());
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5kznycjn/2/

Comment: @Kyojimaru: Thanks. Usually an update just appends a version, but this time JSFiddle changed the URL :)

Comment: Question: the attr() method takes a parameter for the attribute to find inside #foo. However, foo does not have a "lastvalue" attribute. How can this code work, as it looks like magic?

Comment: @Bas R.: Attributes are dynamic. As a `lastValue` attribute is technically not valid HTML I have changed it to use a `data-` attribute (which is valid HTML). :)

Comment: @Bas R.: the previous version would still work on most browsers, but `data-` is the way to go :)